# How to force Mac OS to open links in incognito?

Tags: applescript

How do I modify the [applescript created by user23127 in this link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25375/how-do-i-open-google-chrome-in-incognito-mode-by-default) to force hyperlinks to open in incognito? For instance, clicking links in Mail or other apps to open in incognito.

For reference, the apple script (saved as an app in automator) is:

```
on is_running(appName)
    tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains appName
end is_running

set chrome_running to is_running("Google Chrome")
if chrome_running then
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        repeat with w in (windows)
            if mode of w is "incognito" then
                set index of w to 1
                tell application "System Events" to tell process "Google Chrome"
                    perform action "AXRaise" of window 1
                end tell
                activate
                return
            end if
        end repeat
    end tell
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        make new window with properties {mode:"incognito"}
        activate
    end tell
else
    do shell script "open -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app --args --incognito"
end if
```